# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ihc_init() Как исправить?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Появились ошибки на сайте. Понадобилось при регистрации на сайте загружать изображение, но при попытке загрузить получаю ошибку ERROR: Internal Server Error
В логах вижу такое:

```html
[Fri Nov 15 01:00:52.520987 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1140] [client 77.111.247.202:52164] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare ihc_init() (previously declared in /var/www/www-root/data/www/xxxxxxxx.ru/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/public/init.php:9) in /var/www/www-root/data/www/xxxxxxxx.ru/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/public/init.php on line 87, referer: https://xxxxxxxx.ru/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ihc_manage&tab=register
[Fri Nov 15 01:01:45.515690 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 9407] [client 77.111.247.202:52180] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare ihc_init() (previously declared in /var/www/www-root/data/www/xxxxxxxx.ru/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/public/init.php:9) in /var/www/www-root/data/www/xxxxxxxx.ru/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/public/init.php on line 87, referer: https://xxxxxxxx.ru/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ihc_manage&tab=register
```

Вообще не могу понять как их исправить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим можно сделать? Очень надо. Срочно.

Видно что дублируется функция, но как это исправить не понятно.
Код файла init.php в котором дублируется функция:

```html
<?php
    function ihc_init(){
     /*
      * RUN EVERYTIME ON PUBLIC
      * @param none
      * @return none
      */
     //========== REGISTER SOCIAL MEDIA COOKIE
     if (isset($_COOKIE['ihc_register'])){
      global $ihc_stored_form_values;
      $data = unserialize(stripslashes($_COOKIE['ihc_register']));
      if (is_array($data) && count($data)){
       foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
        $ihc_stored_form_values[$k] = $v;
       }
      }
      setcookie("ihc_register", "", time()-3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);//delete the cookie
     }

     $restrictionOn = true;
     $postid = -1;
     $url = IHC_PROTOCOL . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; /// $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
     $current_user = false;

     if (!empty($_POST['ihcaction'])){
      /// FORM ACTIONS : REGISTER/LOGIN/UPDATE/ RESET PASS/ DELETE LEVEL FROM ACCOUNT PAGE/CANCEL LEVEL FROM ACCOUNT PAGE/ RENEW LEVEL
      ihc_init_form_action($url);
     } else {
      /// LOGOUT / PAY NEW LEVEL
      if (!empty($_GET['ihcdologout'])){
       include_once IHC_PATH . 'public/functions/logout.php';
       ihc_do_logout($url);
      } else if (!empty($_GET['ihcnewlevel'])){
       ihc_do_pay_new_level();
      }


      //// UX BUILDER
      if (isset($_GET['uxb_iframe']) && !empty($_GET['post_id'])){
       return;
      }
      //// UX BUILDER


      /// REDIRECT / REPLACE CONTENT
      $postid = url_to_postid( $url );//getting post id
      $restrictionOn = true;

      if ($postid==0){
       $cpt_arr = ihc_get_all_post_types();
       $the_cpt = FALSE;
       $post_name = FALSE;
       if (count($cpt_arr)){
        foreach ($cpt_arr as $cpt){
         if (!empty($_GET[$cpt])){
          $the_cpt = $cpt;
          $post_name = $_GET[$cpt];
          break;
         }
        }
       }
       if ($the_cpt && $post_name){
        $cpt_id = ihc_get_post_id_by_cpt_name($the_cpt, $post_name);
        if ($cpt_id){
         $postid = $cpt_id;
        }
       } else {
        //test if its homepage
        $homepage = get_option('page_on_front');
        if($url==get_permalink($homepage)) $postid = $homepage;
       }
      }

      $restrictionOn = apply_filters( 'ihc_filter_restriction', $restrictionOn, $postid );
      if ( !$restrictionOn ){
        return;
      }

      ihc_if_register_url($url);//test if is register page
      ihc_block_page_content($postid, $url);//block page

     }

     $restrictionOn = apply_filters( 'ihc_filter_restriction', $restrictionOn, $postid );

     if ( !$restrictionOn ){
       return;
     }

     //// BLOCK INDIVIDUAL PAGE
     ihc_do_block_if_individual_page($postid);

     /////////////BLOCK BY URL
     ihc_block_url($url, $current_user, $postid);//function available in public/functions.php

     /// Block Rules
     ihc_check_block_rules($url, $current_user, $postid);

     /// Hide ADMIN BAR
     ihc_do_show_hide_admin_bar_on_public();

     //echo $postid,'<br/>';
    }
```

Comment: В плагине функция обернута в if function_exists?

Comment: @Krya Если в файле init.php написать if (!function_exists('ihc_init')) вместо function ihc_init() , то сайт  перестаёт работать. Или я не правильно это делаю?

Comment: Неправильно. Должно быть так: if ( !function_exists(...) ) { function ihc_init() ... }

Comment: Спасибо, огромное. Так работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете переопределить функцию если ее обернуть в `function_exists`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'ihc_init' ) ) {
    function ihc_init(){
        ...
    }
}
```